# Default value for select dropdown in Angular 13

Tags: angular, select, drop-down-menu

```
    <select name="role" id="roleId" class="form-control" formControlName="roleId">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option *ngFor="let role of roles" [selected]="selectedRoleId==role.id" value="{{role.id}}">{{role.roleName}}
      </option>
    </select>
```

How do I make the default selection in my dropdown the first item on the list?

I am using a FormGroup in my project and this piece is part of the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you fetch your roles do this

```js
sortRoles(roles = this.roles) {
  const id = roles.findIndex(role => role.id === this.form.value.roleId);
  const dup = [...roles];
  const [role] = dup.splice(id, 1);
  dup.unshift(role);
  return dup;
}
```

Also listen to changes on your form

```js
this.form.roleId.valueChanges
  .subscribe((id) => this.roles = this.sortRoles());
```

Comment: I think you have a good enhancement idea but I need the first role on the list to load in the UI when the page loads.

Comment: That's what it does.